# A question in Corollary Section 7.1 of Hoffman Kunze Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, cayley-hamilton, companion-matrices

I am self studying Chapter -7 of Linear Algebra from  Hoffman Kunze and I have a question in 1st section in last corollary whose image I am adding .

[image]

Image of Theorem 1:

[image]

> I have a question in 1st method. How does theorem 1 can be applied with Cayley Hamilton Theorem to deduce the corollary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x)=c_0+c_1x+\dots+c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+x^k$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&\cdots&0&-c_0\\
1&0&0&\cdots&0&-c_1\\
0&1&0&\cdots&0&-c_2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&-c_{k-2}\\
0&0&0&\cdots&1&-c_{k-1}
\end{pmatrix}$.
Consider $V=F^k$ with standard (ordered) basis $e=[e_1,e_2,\dots,e_k]$, and the linear operator $U:V\to V$ given by $U(v)=Av$. Since vector $e_i$ has coordinates $(0,\dots,1,\dots,0)$ in $e$ ($1$ is on the $i$-th position), it is easy to see:
\begin{eqnarray}
U(e_1) &=& e_2\\
U^2(e_1)&=&U(e_2) = e_3\\
U^3(e_1)&=&U(e_3) = e_4\\
&\vdots&\\
U^{k-1}(e_1)&=&U(e_{k-1}) = e_k\\
U^k(e_1)&=&U(e_k) = -c_0e_1-c_1e_2-c_2e_3-\dots-c_{k-2}e_{k-1}-c_{k-1}e_k.
\end{eqnarray}

Now, note two things. First, $p(U)(e_1)=0$, which is clear from the previous calculations, so $p\in M(e_1,U)$. Second, $Z(e_1,U)=V$, which is also clear from the previous calculations (all basis vectors belong to $Z(e_1,U)$). By Theorem 1(1), $U$-annihilator of $e_1$ is of degree $\dim(Z(e_1,U))=\dim(V)=k$, so it must be $p$. By Theorem 1(3), $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $U$ (hence of $A$ as well). By Cayley-Hamilton, $p$ is also the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (as minimal polynomial divides characteristic, and characteristic polynomial is of order $k$).